# UICollectionViewCell UIImage Lag even with dispatch_async

Tags: ios, swift

Symptom lag appears upon rendering a cell in collection view cell, I've recorded it here https://youtu.be/2utKOpHMshs

I'm not quite sure how the lag is happening and starting to suspect it has something to do with the recipe name element else rather than the UIImage since it's on another thread.

Async function

```
func asyncLoadImage(data: NSData, imageView: UIImageView) {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        var image: UIImage!
        NSLog("loading image")
        image = UIImage(data: data)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            imageView.image = image
            NSLog("render image")
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeListViewController

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!RecipeListCollectionViewCell
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.item] as! Recipe
    cell.recipeName?.text = recipe.name?.uppercaseString
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    if (recipe.photo != nil) {
        asyncLoadImage(recipe.photo!, imageView: cell.recipeImageView)
    }        
    return cell
}
```

UICollectionViewCell:init

```
recipeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height-100))
recipeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
recipeImageView.clipsToBounds = true
self.addSubview(recipeImageView)

recipeName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height-100, width: frame.size.width, height: 50))
recipeName.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1)
recipeName.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
recipeName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
recipeName.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18.00)
self.addSubview(recipeName)
```

Comment: Most likely this is causing: `cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true` and `cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` - try to comment them and test.

Comment: Can you try the following: 1. remove the async code
2. remove the code rasterizationScale
3. please provide me the log that appears in the xcode, this will tell me how much time it is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved by removing the following code

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```